# How do I find my OAuth secret key for Google+?

Tags: android, oauth

According to this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/GettingAnOAuthConsoleKey) the secret key is underneath the consumer id but I only have consumer ID in my console.

if I leave the clientSecret field empty in
 `GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, String clientId, String clientSecret, String code, String redirectUri)`
 I get a 400 bad request error

Where can I find the secret key?

This is how my console looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not [use Android's AccountManager](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android) with the Simple API Access key?

If you want to do it the manual way as in your example, just generate client credentials for an installed application of the type *Other*.

In the future, there will be [Google's Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) which will then provide a more secure way of accessing Google's APIs using an application's signature and no client secret required.